# Фильтрация входящих данных из EditText в Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

В приложении для Android имеется активити с полями для ввода данных. Одно из них EditText с inputType=textCapWords, а другое EditText с inputType=number.

Задался вопросом - может ли злоумышленник каким-нибудь способом, например, в поле с цифрами вставить какие-то другие данные? Нужно ли фильтровать данные при их получении из этих полей перед записью в базу или это лишняя работа?

Данные охраняются не только в базу приложения, но отправляются на сервер. На стороне сервера разумеется проходит дополнительная фильтрация.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, в EditText например с android:inputType="phone" можно вставить только цифры. И если копировать текст и попробовать вставить, у вас этого не выйдет.